# Django, ImportError: cannot import name Celery, possible circular import?

Tags: python, django, celery, importerror

I went through this example here:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

All my tasks are in files called tasks.py.

After updating celery and adding the file from the example django is throwing the following error, no matter what I try:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Celery
```

Is the problem possibly caused by the following?

```
app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS, related_name='tasks')
```

Because it goes through all tasks.py files which all have the following import.

```
from cloud.celery import app
```

**cloud/celery.py**:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os, sys
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from django.conf import settings

BROKER_URL = 'redis://:PASSWORD@localhost'

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'cloud.settings')
app = Celery('cloud', broker=BROKER_URL)
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS, related_name='tasks')

if "test" in sys.argv:
    app.conf.update(
        CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True,
    )
    print >> sys.stderr, 'CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True'

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'test_rabbit_running': {
        "task": "retail.tasks.test_rabbit_running",
        "schedule": 3600, #every hour
    },
    [..]

app.conf.update(
    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE=CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE
)
```

**retail/tasks.py**:

```
from cloud.celery import app

import logging
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
logger = get_task_logger('tasks')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

@app.task
def test_rabbit_running():
    import datetime
    utcnow = datetime.datetime.now()
    logger.info('CELERY RUNNING')
```

The error happens, when I try to access a url that is not valid, like /foobar.

**Here is the full traceback**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 126, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in handle_uncaught_exception
    if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
  File "/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/opt/src/slicephone/cloud/cloud/urls.py", line 52, in 
    urlpatterns +=  patterns('', url(r'^search/', include('search.urls')))
  File "/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 25, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/opt/virtenvs/django_slice/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/opt/src/slicephone/cloud/search/urls.py", line 5, in 
    from handlers import SearchHandler
  File "/opt/src/slicephone/cloud/search/handlers.py", line 15, in 
    from places import handlers as placeshandler
  File "/opt/src/slicephone/cloud/places/handlers.py", line 23, in 
    import api as placesapi
  File "/opt/src/slicephone/cloud/places/api.py", line 9, in 
    from djapi import *
  File "/opt/src/slicephone/cloud/places/djapi.py", line 26, in 
    from tasks import add_single_place, add_multiple_places
  File "/opt/src/slicephone/cloud/places/tasks.py", line 2, in 
    from cloud.celery import app
  File "/opt/src/slicephone/cloud/cloud/celery.py", line 4, in 
    from celery import Celery
  File "/opt/src/slicephone/cloud/cloud/celery.py", line 4, in 
    from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name Celery
```

Comment: please provide full traceback, not just the last line

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Adding the following lines to cloud/celery.py:

```
import celery
print celery.__file__
```

gave me the file itself and not the celery module from the library. After renaming celery.py to celeryapp.py and adjusting the imports all errors were gone.

Note:

That leads to a change in starting the worker:

```
celery worker --app=cloud.celeryapp:app
```

For those running celery==3.1.2 and getting this error:

```
TypeError: unpack_from() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not memoryview
```

Apply the patch mentioned here: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1637

Comment: And don't forget to delete the compiled cloud/celery.pyc in the directory.  If not, you'll continue to get the error.

Comment: I've seen this exact error, I don't see why renaming the file should be necessary when using `from __future__ import absolute_import` but that's what I did.

Comment: Clever solution, I don't know why developers choose celery.py for the default name, creating this problems and having to rely on `from __future__ import absolute_import` everywhere.

Comment: You can't name it any other than `celery`, otherwise you won't be able to call it via `celery worker -A src`

Answer (score 51):

With Django 1.7.5, Celery 3.1.17, and Python 2.7.6 I found that I was still getting these `ImportError: cannot import name Celery`. But only when running tests under PyCharm 4.0.4.

I found that a solution was **not** to rely on `from __future__ import absolute_import` as described in [First Steps with Django](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html). Instead I renamed `proj/proj/celery.py` to `proj/proj/celery_tasks.py` and then changed the content of `__init__.py` to match: `from .celery_tasks import app as celery_app`. No more multiple instances of files named `celery.py` to cause import confusion seemed to be a simpler approach.

Comment: This is exactly what I did to remove any confusion for both the code and myself.

Comment: The above worked for me in django 1.8, but I left `from __future__ import absolute_import` in there and it worked fine.  Though I also had to `rm *.pyc` and restart the dev server.

Comment: I had the same error and a slightly different experience.  In PyCharm 2017.2 I started getting errors about the imports not working.  Turns out it's because I launched PyCharm with the `charm` command on the command line ... bad idea.  That command line inherits from the shell's environment, and on the shell I made my default Python 3.6 and `PYTHONPATH` leaked into my Python2 project in PyCharm.  The solution is to launch PyCharm outside of the terminal, and my problems went away.

Comment: This is exactly the solution for me. `from __future__ import absolute_import` does not work.

Answer (score 17):

got the same error

my celery settings filename which was(celery.py) was conflicting with 'celery' package...

so while doing this-> from celery import Celery ,
 it was raising error- cannot import name Celery

solution->just change the 'celery.py' to something else like 'celery-settings.py'

Comment: Also remove celery.pyc that in the end caused my problem.

Comment: nicely work for me.

Answer (score 13):

In October 2022, `importlib-metadata==5.0.0` was released. In python 3.7, this breaks `kombu==5.2.4` (see [issue#1600](https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/1600)) which is used by the current version of `celery`.

Pin `importlib-metadata==4.13.0` or another version less than 5, or update to python 3.8.

Answer (score 9):

Work for me ( some bug after deploy in server ):
Remove all *.pyc files from project and restart him.

Comment: Been trying for hours. Built the entire code in MacOs, then tried running the same application on Windows and I've only got circular imports. Erased all *.pyc files and now it worked!!! Thank you

Comment: You can do it with `find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -f {} \;`

Answer (score 8):

Did you add the line:

`from __future__ import absolute_import`

to the top of your `cloud/celery.py` module?

Read the breakdown of the example here:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Answer (score 5):

**For someone who want to know what cause this error**:
I have meet this problem just now, then I found the problem --- sys.path.
Maybe you add some path to sys.path like me, I add below code in manage.py,

```
ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
SRC_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'src')
CONF_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'conf')

sys.path.insert(0, SRC_PATH)
sys.path.insert(0, CONF_PATH)
```

so, `from celery import Celery` would search celery in `SRC_PATH` and `CONF_PATH` first, that's the problem.

change  to

```
sys.path.append(SRC_PATH)
sys.path.append(CONF_PATH)
```

It would search in python's `lib` and `site-packages` first. Solved perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, this was my issue :-)

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error. It turns out there was a problem with my Celery version. I upgraded to 3.1 and **celeryd** is now deprecated for this version (http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/whatsnew-3.1.html). So I had to downgrade to the version 3.0.19 that was the previous stable version used for the project, and it works good so far.

```
    pip install celery==3.0.19
```

Anyway, if you don't want to downgrade, the replacement for celeryd in the version 3.1 is **celery worker**. Check here for more info: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

I have face similar type of issue:
**from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery' from 'celery'**

Another simple way to solve this:
If your package have celery configuration in celery.py this is the reason that it is causing problems.
Rename it something like celery_settings.py

Comment: If you rename it you can't then run it as `celery worker -A src`

Answer (score 1):

Note that older Django projects have the `manage.py` script in the same directory as the project directory. That is, the structure looks like this:

```
- proj/
  - proj/__init__.py
  - proj/celery.py
  - proj/urls.py
  - proj/manage.py
  - proj/settings.py
```

instead of this:

```
- proj/
  - proj/__init__.py
  - proj/celery.py
  - proj/settings.py
  - proj/urls.py
- manage.py
```

In this case, you will just have to rename the `celery.app` file to something different, like `celeryapp.py` as suggested in the accepted answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue on a FastAPI app running on Python 3.7. None of the solutions from this thread were working for me. I fixed the issue on my app by upgrading Python to 3.8.

Answer (score 1):

If the above error i.e. `ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery' from 'celery' (/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/__init__.py)` is coming and the python version is being used as 3.7.*, then due to a bug in `importlib-metadata` library because of its latest release.

So, to fix the above issue please use this version in your python dependencies list:

- **pip install importlib-metadata==4.13.0**

Alternately, if you are using Docker file to build the project, change the python version from 3.7 to 3.8 and it should work fine.

For me, it worked. Please use the below link for a detailed look:

[Django_celery_python_3.7_issue](https://django.fun/en/qa/430090/)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.

Seems that `from __future__ import absolute_import` DOES NOT work for Python 2.6.1, still not raising an error.

Upgraded to Python 2.7.5 and it just worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my django application I had the same error. Version Django 4, Celery 5. My my problem is that I run Celery from directory with file celery.py, but it is necessary from directory with manage.py.
Slava Ukraini!

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32370813)